# Is there a way to make qmke store qml .cpp files in a directory like mocs or objs?

Tags: qmake

I just started using Qt 5.12.4. I've just compiled some working code that uses QML and no the output directory contains a bunch of files that start with qml_[Name of a QML File].cpp

Is there a QMake directive that I can add to the .pro file so that those files will be generated in a specific folder? (Like the MOCS_DIR directive for moc cpp files)